# Mysql - find fields with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to contruct a query, from keywords entered by a user in a text-field, which will do the following: Take the keywords and search in a table, after which car has all the given keywords.
My table looks like this:

```
field_id | car_id | keyword |
----------------------------
1        | 5       | 1989   |
-----------------------------
2        | 8       | old    |
-----------------------------
3        | 8       | ford   |
-----------------------------
4        | 2       | audi   |
-----------------------------
5        | 5       | red    |
-----------------------------
6        | 8       | cheap  |
-----------------------------
```

Say if the user searched for "old", "ford" and "cheap", the car_id 8 should be returned because it contains all the keywords. How would you pull this off?

Comment: Don't you mean it'll return car_id 8?

Comment: don't you mean car id 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes you know the number of key words entered and you want an a match on all of them
In addition it assumes that a keyword, car_id are unique. (car_Id 8 can't have cheap twice)

```
Select car_ID from myTable
Where keyword in ('old','ford','cheap')
group by car_ID
having count(*) = 3
```